# cross domain ajax iframe javascript issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, cross-domain, mobile-safari

I created an iframe in Domain A and used that iframe in my other domain, Domain B by calling it via AJAX. I also implemented a javascript back button for my app in the iframe in Domain A using `history.go(-1)`.

When I view my page now using IE,Firefox, Chrome everything works perfectly but the javascript back button doesnt work for Safari. It seems like it calls the window instead of the iframe.

I created a hidden iframe (thought it was a cross domain issue) and had no luck.  Afterwards, I created a home button in my frame which took me to the orignial url source my back button started to work in Domain B (prob iframe source has changed).

What is the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The way i have implemented something like this in the past is:

- domain A creates a hidden iframe that opens a page on domain B.
- domain B gathers information it needs to send back and then redirects to specially prepared page back on domain A. using GET data to send it's result.
- The page back in domain A will uses the GET parameter to creates a javascript block to push the message to the original page (using window.parent or window.top)

This method of course assumes you get to manipulate client implementation on both ends and server implementation on the side of Domain B.